# Filter multiple CSV for text and create new files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have about 2500 CSV files each around 20MB in terms of file size. I am trying to filter out certain rows from each file and save that to a new file.

So, if i have :

```
File 1 :
    Row1
    Row2
    Row3
File 2 : 
    Row2
    Row3 
and so on..
```

If i filter for all files and select "Row2" as filter text the new folder should have all the files with only rows that match the filter text.

Looking through some forums, I came up with the following that might help me filter the rows, but Im not sure how I can do it recursively, plus I also don't know if this is a fast enough method. Any help is appreciated.

```
Get-Content "C:\Path to file" | Where{$_ -match "Rowfiltertext*"} | Out-File "Path to Out file"
```

I'm using windows so I guess Powershell type of solution would be the best here.

The text to be filtered will always be in the first column.

Thanks
Siddhant

Comment: How do you select the rows to remove? Can the search pattern be anywhare in the row or should it be a value from a specific column?

Comment: both the `Select-String` cmdlet and the `switch` structure can load a file ... and do it _quickly_. both can also handle regex patterns. i would try one of them ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Theo : The text to be filtered will always be in the first column.

Updated the question with this info as well.

Comment: Still some more questions: [1]Do all csv files have the exact same headers/fields? [2]Should the output file also be a csv with headers or just a text file without caring about fields and field order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two fast ways of searching for a string inside (text) files:

**1) using switch**

```
$searchPattern = [regex]::Escape('Rowfiltertext')  # for safety escape regex special characters
$sourcePath    = 'X:\Path\To\The\Csv\Files'
$outputPath    = 'X:\FilteredCsv.txt'

# if you also need to search inside subfolders, append -Recurse to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # iterate through the lines in the file and output the ones that match the search pattern
    switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        $searchPattern { $_ }
    }
} | Set-Content -Path $outputPath  # add -PassThru to also show on screen
```

**2) using Select-String**

```
$searchPattern = [regex]::Escape('Rowfiltertext')  # for safety escape regex special characters
$sourcePath    = 'X:\Path\To\The\Csv\Files'
$outputPath    = 'X:\FilteredCsv.txt'

# if you also need to search inside subfolders, append -Recurse to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet
Get-ChildItem  -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern $searchPattern).Line
} | Set-Content -Path $outputPath  # add -PassThru to also show on screen
```

---

In case you want to output a new csv file for every original file,

use:

**3) using switch**

```
$searchPattern = [regex]::Escape('Rowfiltertext')  # for safety escape regex special characters
$sourcePath    = 'X:\Path\To\The\Csv\Files'
$outputPath    = 'X:\FilteredCsv'

if (!(Test-Path -Path $outputPath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $outputPath -ItemType Directory
}

# if you also need to search inside subfolders, append -Recurse to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.csv' -File) | ForEach-Object {
    # create a full target filename for the filtered output csv
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath ('New_{0}' -f $_.Name)
    # iterate through the lines in the file and output the ones that match the search pattern
    $result = switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        $searchPattern { $_ }
    }
    $result | Set-Content -Path $outFile  # add -PassThru to also show on screen
}
```

**4) using Select-String**

```
$searchPattern = [regex]::Escape('Rowfiltertext')  # for safety escape regex special characters
$sourcePath    = 'X:\Path\To\The\Csv\Files'
$outputPath    = 'X:\FilteredCsv'

# if you also need to search inside subfolders, append -Recurse to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet
(Get-ChildItem  -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.csv' -File) | ForEach-Object {
    # create a full target filename for the filtered output csv
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath ('New_{0}' -f $_.Name)
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern $searchPattern).Line | Set-Content -Path $outFile  # add -PassThru to also show on screen
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Re. "fast enough method":
Get-Content is extremely slow.
You could use "System.IO.StreamReader" instead, i.e. read the complete file content into a string, then split this string into rows and so on, e.g.:

```
[System.IO.FileStream]$objFileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($Csv.FullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
[System.IO.StreamReader]$objStreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($objFileStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$strFileContent = ($objStreamReader.ReadToEnd())
$objStreamReader.Close()
$objStreamReader.Dispose()
$objFileStream.Close()
$objFileStream.Dispose()

[string[]]$arrFileContent = $strFileContent -split("`r`n")
```